# Python string index mistake 'builten_function_or_method' and 'object is not subscriptable'

Tags: python

```
language = "python"
print(language[0]), print("is at index 0")
print(" ")
print(language[1]), print("is at index 1")
print(" ")
print(language[2]), print("is at index 2")
print(" ")
print(language[3]), print("is at index 3")
print(" ")
print(language[4]), print("is at index 4")
print(" ")
print(language[5]), print("is at index 5")

print("")
name = "Finley"
print(name[::2])

#snippet I previously posted
teamName = input("Please put in your team's name: ")
if teamName[1]() == "a":
  print("invalid team")
```

I'm a student and I'm not quite sure what I did wrong.

edit: the snippet I previously posted does not appear to be the source of the error, so here's the full extent of the code

Comment: What input are you giving at the prompt, and can you please [edit] your question to include the full traceback of the error?

Comment: The code you have posted does not reproduce the error  you describe.

Answer (score 0):

update: it was the "()" in line 19 the remnants of a .isalfnum(), Thank you for the feedback.